# How to correctly handle System.Web.HttpRequestValidationException

Tags: asp.net-mvc

> System.Web.HttpRequestValidationException: A potentially dangerous
>   Request.Form value was detected from the client

When rising exception above usually suggest disable validation request with the attribute below

```
    [ValidateInput(false)]
    public ActionResult Save(string content)
    {
        System.IO.File.WriteAllText(fileName, content);
        return View();
    }
```

Then why even come up with this verification? How to correctly handle this exception?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When the URL request (Your example: `string content`) contains the dangerous keywords :" >, ?, <, etc... ".
If you want handle this exception (Example: allow these), you can follow sample code:

```
using System;
using System.Web.Mvc;

namespace Custom {
    public class CustomValidateInput : FilterAttribute, IAuthorizationFilter {
        /// <summary>
        /// Called when authorization is required.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="filterContext">The filter context.</param>
        /// <exception cref="System.ArgumentNullException">filterContext</exception>
        public void OnAuthorization(AuthorizationContext filterContext) {
            if (filterContext == null) {
                throw new ArgumentNullException("filterContext");
            }

            //Set disable validation request
            filterContext.Controller.ValidateRequest = false;

            //----------Your code handle here------------//

        }
    }
}
```

and

```
[CustomValidateInput]
public ActionResult Save(string content)
{
    System.IO.File.WriteAllText(fileName, content);
    return View();
}
```

Comment: Tell me how to read the "content" parameter from your attribute?

Comment: Before, you add new reference to `System.Web.Routing` and add new code: `if (filterContext.RequestContext.HttpContext.Request.Url != null) {
                var content = filterContext.RequestContext.HttpContext.Request.Url.Query;
            }`

Comment: Because you don't use direct `filterContext.RequestContext.HttpContext.Request["content"]` .

Comment: @LazyCatIT It is not working in POST request, In post request filterContext.RequestContext.HttpContext.Request.Url.Query is null, it is a solution for GET requests